# Scheduled capture from COM port

Tags: windows, command-line-interface, serial

I want to capture COM output to a daily file. I can capture manually, using something like RS232 Data Logger, but I want to run a scheduled task so I get a daily log of the data captured.

Is there anything out there command line based (from a Windows server) so I could knock up a script to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I am not a windows expert and can not vouch for the existence of what I used to do when DOS 2.0 was the (almost) only OS to run PCs, but, you were able to copy the information coming through any port to a file with the simple command :

copy comX filename

the problem is, you need to inject a ctrl-Z into this stream to close the transmission and write the file and one of the same in the data stream, would break the copy operation as well.

My 2 cents. Nothing more :)